# Best practice on HTTP queries in ES6

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

Recently I started with ES6 and got an obvious task to query some API. There are some tools to do so(like https://www.npmjs.com/package/es6-request)  as well as built-in `fetch` method. 
But what is common to query API in real-world applications?

I tried to search for a while and haven't find an answer. If I mistaken please point a link in comments and I'll remove the question if needed.

Comment: There's no 'best practice' (that's why BP questions are closed). Pick the library of your choice. `fetch` is ok.

Comment: `fetch` is the common option at the moment. You can't go wrong with it. Remember to add polyfill if you want to support legacy browsers.

Comment: thanks for answers, guys